# $f(x)= sin(x)^{3}+cos(x)^{3}$ prove ${f}''(x)= \frac{3}{2}(cos(x)+sin(x))(3sin(2x)-2)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

$f(x)= \sin(x)^{3}+\cos(x)^{3}$

prove  that  ${f}''(x)=  \frac{3}{2}(cos(x)+sin(x))\, (3sin(2x)-2)$

I  tried  to  solve  it  but  I  can't  complete  it.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\sin^3x+\cos^3x=(\sin x+\cos x)(\sin^2x-\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x)=(\sin x+\cos x)\left(1-\dfrac{\sin2x}2\right)$$